# When does Logen Ninefingers kill this particular person?

Tags: novel, joe-abercrombie, the-first-law

If you haven't read *The First Law* by Joe Abercrombie, stop reading this and go start reading **that**.

In the second half of *The Last Argument of Kings*, Crummock-i-Phail says that Logen Ninefingers, The Bloody Nine,

> killed his son

But I don't remember that happening explicitly. Can anyone tell me if it was explicitly stated? Does Logen just not notice or remember?

Comment: It's been too long since I read those books. I vaguley remember something happening to a nameless character during the battle they were in. I thought Crummock's comment meant that this character was the person he's talking about. Sorry about saying it so roundabout but I don't want to spoiler. I'd have to look at my copy to be sure anyway. Might be that I remember it wrong. But to answer your last question: When Logen becomes the Bloody Nine he turns into a raging killing machine. He often doesn't fully remember what happend nor does he care when he's in that state.

Comment: It's been a while since I read this, but wasn't his son killed by Bethod and nailed to an iron cross on a horse?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got out my copy to answer this one.
To answer your question if this is explicitly told in the book, yes it is.<strike>*, but a little obscure. Propably to keep it as a revelation for all those who didn't realise it right away.*</strike>

> The passage is on page 243:
>
> ***A boy-child cowered, and slithered away on his back, clutching at a great shield and an axe too big for him to lift***. The Bloody-Nine laughed at his fear, teeth bared bright and smiling. **A tiny voice seemed to whisper for restraint**, but the Bloody-Nine hardly heard it. **His sword hard-swung split big shield and small boy together and sprayed blood across** the dirt and the stone and **the stricken faces of the men watching**.
>
> (Emphasis mine)
>
> There is no name given in this passage, but it’s clear the Bloody-Nine has done something horrible by all accounts and Logen even tried to hold him back but failed.
>
> Then later on page 319:
>
> ***Especially not the man who killed my son, eh?*** Logen felt himself go cold, from the roots of his hair to the tips of his fingers. What did you think? That I wouldn’t know? The hillman leaned back to look Logen in the eye. **You slaughtered him before the whole world**, now, didn’t you? **You butchered little Rond like a sheep for the pot, and him just as helpless as one**.
>
> (Emphasis mine)
>
> The earlier passage doesn’t specifically state that this boy is Crummock’s son, but it can be assumed that only his son would partake in the battle and could be described as a boy-child.
>
> There are also Crummock’s other comments. That he was slaughtered like a helpless sheep (*the boy clutching his shield while trying to get away on his back*) and having been killed “before the whole world” (*the men watching the scene with stricken faces and getting sprayed with the boy’s blood*).
>
> Took another look into the book because of *Duralumin's* comment. Together with this passage it becomes very clear that Logen killed Crummock's son during the battle. Here Crummock and his three children are first introduced.
>
> Page 95:
>
> *A **little boy** came next. He had a **round shield across his back, much too wide for him**, and a **great axe he was lugging along in both hands**.*
>
> (Emphasis mine)

As to the question if Logen didn't notice or didn't remember. Logen and the Bloody-Nine are not exactly the same 'person'. He often doesn't remember what happend when he becomes the Bloody-Nine. At least not fully. After all...

> Page 255:
>
> *He wanted to weep. For the death of a good man. For the fact that he **might've been the one to cause it**.*
>
> He doesn't seem to remember killing one of his closest companions, but he seems to suspect that he did.

And the Bloody-Nine simply doesn't care.

Comment: I think I remember something about the son of Crummock-i-Phail being presented with some emphasys on the big shield he was carring. I know for sure that I didn't have any doubts about the fact that he killed the son even before Crummock-i-Phail said anything about it.

Comment: @Duralumin You're right. Edited my answer and added a quote of the page you mentioned. Check it out.

Comment: Nice! So my memory still works =). The thing is, I wrote emphasis wrong somehow. It's  offending my eyes! But I can't edit it without deleting the comment and reposting it. But now it's too late, because I would change the order of the comments. It's a hard life.

Comment: It is clearly in the first quote. Excellent answer.